# Change Glyphicon on table collapse

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 5 that simulates a treeview by using a table that can expand and collapse.

```
    <div class="table table-condensed" style="border: 1px; border-collapse:collapse;">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{ int i = 0;}
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".stephistory_@i" id ="stephistory_@i" style="background-color:cadetblue" >
                        <td class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="icon_@i"></td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExecutionTime)</td>
                    </tr>
                    foreach (var step in item.JobHistories)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="hiddenRow">
                                <div class="collapse stephistory_@i">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => step.ExecutionTime)</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(document).on('show.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
        $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
        $('#' + event.target.id).addClass('glyphicon-minus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus');
    });

    $(document).on('hide.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
        $('#' + event.target.id).addClass('glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus');
    });
});
```

This almost works but the addClass/removeClass only targets the first row of the table. How to I pick up the dynamically created id?

Edit

I've updated the code to reflect current situation. Also some of the table columns have been removed to make things easier to read.

Comment: Use `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` methods.

Comment: I've altered the question to reflect the changes I've tried. This now almost works but I need to somehow pick up the dynamically created id.

Comment: There isn't one as I wanted to change this to pickup '#icon' + the same number from the row id

Comment: @AndrewLackenby what is this `class="class=" table table-condensed"`? Might want to edit that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event Delegation:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(document).on('show.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
            $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
            $('#icon').addClass('glyphicon-minus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus');
        });

        $(document).on('hide.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
            $('#icon').addClass('glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And some lecture:

> **[Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**
>
> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

For the question you asked in the comments can you try this:

```
<div data-targetid="@i" class="collapse stephistory_@i">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => step.ExecutionTime)</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(document).on('show.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
            $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
            $(this).find('td').first().addClass('glyphicon-minus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus');
        });

        $(document).on('hide.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function () {
            var targetId = $(this).data("targetid");
            $("#icon_" + targetId).addClass('glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is almost working except the hidden.bs.collapse event doesn't seem to be firing.

Comment: @AndrewLackenby Updated, try to use `hide.bs.collapse` instead of `hidden.bs.collapse`

Comment: That event now fires but to pick up the correct table row, I changed ('#icon') to $('#' + event.target.id) and added id="icon_@i" where the row in the table is generated. This works for expanding the row but when the row is collapsed, the wrong id is picked up.

Comment: @AndrewLackenby I've updated my answer, hope I'll help you to find your way, do not hesitate to accept the answer if you are satisfied enough.